# Como implementar 'check in' no tfs 2012 somente aprovado pelo revisor?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, estilo-de-codificação, team-foundation-server

Gostaria de saber se é possível e como faço para travar o *Check In* para que apenas o revisor possa subir o código, ou que não seja possível sem sua permissão.

Para garantir que casos em que voltar com *With Comments* ou *Needs Work*, o código não terá *Check In* até a aprovação de um revisor.

Comment: @Paulo Roberto Obrigado por adicionar as tags, eu ainda não tenho reputação para isso.

Comment: Disponha. porém quem adicionou foi o @iuristona como você pode ver aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/5209/revisions eu só corrigi pois ele tinha colocado `sever` ao invés de `server`

Comment: Eu não tinha olhado o histórico de revisões como você fez a mais recente achei que tinha sido você, então muito obrigado pela ajuda @iuristona

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo o que é dito neste artigo: http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/2012/12/custom-code-review-checkin-policy.html, você precisar criar uma custom policy.

E foi exatamente o que o autor fez, e disponibilizou o código fonte aqui: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c476b708-77a8-4065-b9d0-919ab688f078.

Comment: Eu adicionei esse complemento e desmarquei os checkboxes, colocando para o estado para poder fazer o Check In ser Looks Good. Porém só está sendo possível juntar as tarefas que deram Looks Good logo na primeira revisão, se der Needs Work e depois Looks Good não é possível mais fazer o Check In